# How to set text of a button randomly?

Tags: java, swing, random

is it possible to set a button / buttons text randomly e.g.

case 1;

I have 1 button and 3 text and I want to randomly set the text of the button to one of the three text, when a the button is pressed.

```
String text1 = "Lucky", text2 = "Not lucky", text3 = "BadLuck, press the button again";
JButton button = new Jbutton(""); // I want this button to have one of the text from above randomly.
```

case 2;

I have 3 buttons and 1 text and I want to randomly give the text to one of the three buttons

```
String text = "I was chosen";
JButton button = new Jbutton("Press me"); // when this button is pressed, I want at randomly for one of the buttons below to get the text "I was chosen".
JButton button1 = newJbutton("");
JButton button2 = newJbutton("");
JButton button3 = newJbutton("");
```

Thanks in advance!

edited:

```
String text = "text";
JButton[] arr = {button1, button2, button3};
Random r = new Random();
arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)].setText(text);
```

Comment: Put strings in a List, generate a random list index and get that index.

Comment: in a list of array? like this... arraylist[] list{"String1", "String2", "String3"};

Comment: I would use a List (e.g. ArrayList) not an array, but an array also works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Case 1

```
String []texts = {"X","Y","Z"};
Random r = new Random();
JButton button = new JButton(texts[r.nextInt(texts.length)];
```

### Case 2

```
text = "I was chosen";
JButton button1 = new Jbutton("");
JButton button2 = new Jbutton("");
JButton button3 = new Jbutton("");
List<JButton> buttons = Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3);
Random r = new Random();
buttons.get(r.nextInt(buttons.size())).setText(text);
```

---

### Edit Answer

```
String text = "text";
JButton[] arr = {button1, button2, button3};
Random r = new Random();
JButton b = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
b.setText(text);
b.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @tintinmy, hi, the buttons are already preset and, won't using your method create new buttons.

Comment: Creating `button1`,`button2`... and so on is boring work to do and make more LOC. So I always make arrays. If you want to work with the preset buttons that will make your work harder to maintain.

Comment: because the buttons, I have are doing multiple Jobs, I have to make all the buttons individually. Is it possible to use your method with how I have created my buttons?

Comment: @user3288493 I had make some changes please see.

Comment: I have a look, can I also ask for one more favor please, how can you make the button which the text is written on get disabled? e.g. if the text goes on button 2, I want button2 to get disabled.

Comment: Store the random integer in one variable. Now change the text and also disable it. Simple :)

Comment: So store this like buttons.get(r.nextInt(buttons.size())).setText(text); in a variable like this? store = buttons.get(r.nextInt(buttons.size())).setText(text);

Comment: No. int index = r.nextInt(buttons.size()); buttons.get(index).setText(text); buttons.get(index).setEnabled(false);

Comment: I had to change the code a bit to make it work before, I am going to paste it above in my post. Now it won't get disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array in both cases to achieve what you want, using a random number to select the text.

For case one per example:

```
String[] arr = {"Lucky", "Not lucky", "BadLuck, press the button again"};
Random r = new Random();
JButton button = new JButton(arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
```

This is the same process for case two with an array of `JButton`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<JButton> buttons = Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3);
List<String> texts = Arrays.asList(text1, text2, text3);

Random rand = new Random();
buttons.get(rand.nextInt()).setText(texts.get(rand.nextInt()));
```

Comment: GGrec, it is giving me an error on the word List "List<JButton>"